# How can I add a date stamp to comments added

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple form for readers to add comments. The comments entered are listed on the website when added. I would like to register the date the comment was entered and list that underneath the comment itself, as shown on the website. Can someone assist me with the JS code for this?
Thanks, Paul

```js
const field = document.querySelector('textarea');
const comments = document.getElementById('comment-box');


// array to store the comments
var comments_arr = [];

if(!localStorage.commentData){localStorage.commentData = [];}
else{
  comments_arr = JSON.parse(localStorage.commentData);
}

// to generate html list based on comments array
const display_comments = () => {
  let list = '<ul>';
   comments_arr.forEach(comment => {
    list += `<li>${comment}</li>`;
  })
  list += '</ul>';
  comments.innerHTML = list;
}

submit.onclick = function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    const content = field.value;
    if(content.length > 0){ // if there is content
      // add the comment to the array
      comments_arr.unshift(content);
      localStorage.commentData = JSON.stringify(comments_arr);
      // re-genrate the comment html list
      display_comments();
      // reset the textArea content 
      field.value = '';
    }
}
window.addEventListener('load', display_comments);
```

```html
<link href="comment.css" rel="stylesheet">

<form>
    <textarea id="comment" placeholder="Your response pls." value=""></textarea>
</form>
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="add">
    <h4>Responses</h4>
       <div id="comment-box"></div>

<script src="comment.js"></script>
```

Comment: Make each comment an object containing the comment and a timestamp (or an array having them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**if you only want date stamp then remove the var current_time from the display_comments() function.**

```
const display_comments = () => {
    var date = new Date();
    var current_date = date.getFullYear()+"-"+(date.getMonth()+1)+"-"+ date.getDate();
    var current_time = date.getHours()+":"+date.getMinutes()+":"+ date.getSeconds();
    var date_time = current_date+" "+current_time;
    let list = '<ul>';
    comments_arr.forEach(comment => {
    list += `<li>${comment}   created at :  ${date_time}</li>`;
    })
    list += '</ul>';
    comments.innerHTML = list;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul, with the entry of a new comment, the old comments get updated date/time stamps. I would like to keep the original date/time stamps, even when a new comment is added. Any easy fix for this? Thanks.

Comment: @PaulvanKlaveren yes thats because you are using forEach loop . so again and again you are creating data inside the HTML dom (li) . so again and again timestamp is assigning to your text box . instead of running your whole array , you should push your last item inside the array and that should be added to your <li> . using that time stamp will not be repeated .

Comment: Okay, will try to work on that.

Comment: I know what you mean and I made a few attempts but can't seem to be able resolve this. can you pls assist? Paul

Comment: yes definitely . what can i help you?

Comment: Maybe show me how to "instead of running your whole array , you should push your last item inside the array and that should be added to your <li> . using that time stamp will not be repeated . " I am okay with html and css, but JS is still a mystery to me.

Comment: Ok . More Working in js will make your mystery to a beautiful memories !! I will do to answer your question

Comment: i have added another answer . check that out , if any changes required then comment below .  !! HAPPY CODING !!

Answer (score 0):

```js
    let textbox=document.getElementById("textbox")
    let comments=document.getElementById("comments")
    let add=()=>{
        let value=textbox.value
        let ul=document.getElementById("ul")
        let list=document.createElement("li")
        var date = new Date();
        var current_date = date.getFullYear()+"-"+(date.getMonth()+1)+"-"+ date.getDate();
        var hours = date.getHours();
        var minutes = date.getMinutes();
        var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
        hours = hours % 12;
        hours = hours ? hours : 12;
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
        var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
        var date_time = current_date+" "+strTime;
        list.innerHTML=`comment:${value}`+"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"+`Created At:${date_time}`
        ul.insertBefore(list,ul.firstElementChild)
        textbox.value=""
    }
```

```html
<textarea id="textbox" placeholder="Your response pls." value=""></textarea>
<button id="btn" onclick="add()">Add</button>
<div id="comments">
    <h4>Responses</h4>
    <ul id="ul"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Rahul, can you also reset the 'textbox value" and list the comments in reverse order, so latest on top. I had that in my original code but I am not sure how to change that in the one you just uploaded

Comment: I also noticed that the comments now disappear when I refresh the page. This was earlier solved by adding "window.addEventListener('load', display_comments);" This does not seem to work in this case

Comment: yes because you have used localstorage to store data . that's why it is being stored even after refreshing the page .

Comment: reset of textbox value already done

Comment: Thanks Rahul, I will give up on this for now. Takes too much time for you and me. Cheers

Comment: i have edited my answer check out . new comment will be pushed in first and after enter textbox will be empty . the only thing you want to do is implement a local storage to store all the data !!

Comment: if any changes you want comment below . we are always there to help you !!

Comment: Will work on local storage issue. Cheers

Comment: I was able to push the data to local storage, but how can I retrieve it when refreshing the page?